# NSArrayController vs NSMutableArray - When do you use a NSArrayController?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsarraycontroller

Working my way through one of my first Cocoa OS X projects where I'm grabbing remote XML data and storing objects in an NSMutableArray.

Today when I opened IB for the first time in the project I discovered the object NSArrayController.

Fairly basic question - When would I use one over the other? I am **not** using a TableView in my application and most things I read talk about binding it to a tabel view.

I am doing a bit of array manipulation though in that I add/remove/modify objects from the array at will. Is there a benefit to one over the other?

Comment: If you need to support [bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000167i) then use `NSArrayController` otherwise use `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: If you don't need cocoa bindings then use NSMutableArray - NSArrayController and NSMutableArray are completely different things; read up on Cocoa Bindings!

Answer (score 0):

With what you described, create a custom data class. So each object of that class manipulates the data however you need and each object represents a record of data. Now with this if you wish to show your data, then subclass nsarraycontroller and bind to this. This controller can be setup to use the custom data class. If you are using the data internally, simply instatiate however many you wish and use NSSet. I recommend NSSet because it guarantee's uniqueness.

Hope this helps.

P.S. NSMutableSet also exists.